# Crash on method call "Could not execute method of the activity"

Tags: android, sql, crash

I'm trying to implement a Log In system from my Android application to a database stored in MS SQL Server 2008. Connection to the server works, the problem comes when I call logIn method for users to connect on connection helper class to compare password matching.

This is the function that is executed when log in button is clicked:

```
public void onLogInButtonClicked(View v){
        final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        String userName = login.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("Pass Entered:" + pass);
        System.out.println("User Entered" + userName);


        if (connector.logIn(userName, pass)){

            //Creates Intent from new Activity to be launched
            Intent k = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

            //Sends login name to activity k
            k.putExtra("loginName", userName);
            //Starts new Activity
            startActivity(k);


        }
        else
        {
            //toast log in unsuccessful
        }
    }
```

logIn method on Connector class is as follows:

```
boolean logIn(String name, String password){
        System.out.println("I'm in LogIn method");
        java.sql.ResultSet result = null;
        boolean log = false;
         try {
             connection = this.getConnection();
             if (connection != null) {

                    //String for the login query
                    String statement = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" 
                                    + name + "'";      
                    System.out.println(statement);

                    Statement select = connection.createStatement();
                    result = select.executeQuery(statement);
                    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
                    if(result.getString(1) == password) log = true;

                    result.close();
                    result = null;
                    closeConnection();
             } 
             else {
                    System.out.println("Error: No active Connection");
                    return log;
             }
         }  catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return log;
    }
```

I don't even get to see the "I'm in logIn method" in the console, which makes me guess the app crashes before getting into it, although the crash occurs in the line where the method is called.

Here is the log:

```
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 11 more
04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace in the log?  The last line indicates a NullPointerException, which is likely the root cause.

Comment: Only this appear after that:  04-25 23:32:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(795): at com.gmat.app.AppActivity.onLogInButtonClicked(AppActivity.java:35) line 35 stands for the line where connector.logIn() method is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your connector object is null.  Did you forget to initialize it or scope it incorrectly? Post up where connector is initialized if that wasn't enough to help you find it

Comment: I initialized it above the posted method, simply by Connector connector;

Comment: @Gmat `Connector connector` is a declaration.  `connector = new Connector();` is an initialization.  Or you can do both in the same line: `Connector connector = new Connector();`

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so stupid now, looks like I need a rest, thank you again.

Comment: @Gmat no problem - happens to everyone :)